# Maven release plugin SSL problems

Tags: java, maven, ssl, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

In my CI (gitlab) I'm using maven from docker to perform the build of the artifact and the deploy on an *archiva* respository.

The archiva respository uses a SSL certificate generated with *letsencrypt*.

I can sucessfully deploy the artifact on *archiva* with:

```
 mvn clean package -B deploy -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/mavenKeystore
```

I'm passing the keystore with as a cli parameters: everything works fine.

But with the release-plugin the `trustStore` parameter is ignored:

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare -B release:perform -DscmCommentPrefix='[ci skip]' -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/mavenKeystore
```

With this command I get the SSL error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found, I need to pass the `trustStore` as a parameter for the `deploy` goal. This works:

```
mvn release:prepare -B release:perform -DscmCommentPrefix='[ci skip]' -Dgoals='deploy -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/mavenKeystore'
```